# Plotting the last data point in sets of box plots in R

Tags: r, dataset, boxplot

I have a number of data sets, and what I'd like to do is to make a box plot for each of the data set and plot the last data point in each box plot. The formula I came up with is:

```
par(mfrow=c(4,6))
for (i in 2:24) {wb[, i] <- as.numeric(as.character( wb[, i] ))}
for (i in 2:24) {boxplot(wb[,i], main=colnames(wb[i]))} 
for (i in 2:24) {points(wb[1,i])}
```

While I am getting box plots for each data set, for some reason I cannot see last data points. I simply want to see where the current data is compared to historical movements. Also I'm wondering if there is a way to make a title for the plot created by par function?

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

All the points are being added to the final boxplot, because this part of the plot is the active plotting region when you've finished plotting the boxplots. You just need to change the order of the plotting slightly to:

```
par(mfrow=c(4,6))
for (i in 2:24) {
  wb[, i] <- as.numeric(as.character( wb[, i] ))
  boxplot(wb[,i], main=colnames(wb[i])) 
  points(wb[1,i])
}
```

Comment: Thanks - it works, but it seems like multiple plots are drawn using the function. I don't get how multiple data points can be plotted using points(wb[1,i]). I attached the plots to the post. Do you know why is this happening?

Comment: I'm surprised that this code is leading to more than one point on each plot, maybe you can provide (a sample of) your data, and the code that shows the problem.